# How can I Pass `json` Data from controller to View and use that to form a table?

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to pass list as `json` string from Controller to View through Ajax, and want to show that `json` string in table Format but i am just getting plain `json` string in View.

Contoller Code

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetRegRequests()
        {
            var model = new TaskManagementEntities().RegRequests.ToList();
            return Json(model,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Here's the Code of of View.

```
 <div id="showRequest">
        <table class="table-responsive reqtab">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
            <th>Req ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and script tag

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: @Url.Action("MasterAdmin", "Index"),
        dataType: 'json',
        success:
            function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $(".reqtab tbody").append("<tr><td>" + result.first_name + "</td><td>" + result.last_name + "</td><td>" + result.user_name +"</td><td>"+ result.password+"</td></tr>")
            }
    })
</script>
```

I am also not getting the table headers instead i am getting just plain json data and browser console is showing following error. i am not sure this error is related or not.

```
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:16
```

**How can i pass this json String to View and use it to form a table ?**

Comment: You should load jquery.js before jquery.unobtrusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to include `JQuery` plugin , that's why console show you need `jQuery` not defined.

Add script before `jquery.unobtrusive` in your html :

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

In addition, ajax result you return is `List(array)` type, if you want to display all data, **you must for each them**. Otherwise, you get `undefined` values.

code:

```
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("MasterAdmin", "Index")', // and use 
        dataType: 'json',
        success:
            function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                result.forEach(element =>
                        $(".reqtab tbody").append("<tr><td>" + element.first_name + "</td><td>" + element.user_name + "</td><td>" + element.password +"</td><td>"+ element.id+"</td></tr>")
                    );
            }
    })
</script>
```